# Ruby: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby, encoding, character-encoding, rubygems

I'm writing a Django project that uses the [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) language.  I'm using the [django-css](http://github.com/dziegler/django-css) application to do this.  My colleague is getting the following error, but I am not.  I suspect that this might be because the encoding is wrong on the file being compiled.  The weird thing is that we cloned from the same hg repo so I don't see why his files' encoding would be wrong and mine right.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /qa/
Caught an exception while rendering: /home/rajoy/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/less-1.2.21/lib/less/engine.rb:49:in `gsub': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from /home/rajoy/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/less-1.2.21/lib/less/engine.rb:49:in `prepare'
    from /home/rajoy/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/less-1.2.21/lib/less/engine.rb:30:in `parse'
    from /home/rajoy/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/less-1.2.21/lib/less/engine.rb:45:in `to_css'
    from /home/rajoy/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/less-1.2.21/lib/less/command.rb:58:in `parse'
    from /home/rajoy/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/less-1.2.21/lib/less/command.rb:51:in `run!'
    from /home/rajoy/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/less-1.2.21/bin/lessc:102:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin/lessc:19:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin/lessc:19:in `<main>'
```

I have ruby 1.8.6 and gems 1.3.6.

My colleague has ruby 1.8.7 and gems 1.9.1.

What are the possible reasons for why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ruby version. The 1.9 changed the way String encodings are handled.

http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string

Comment: But he has ruby 1.8.7 not 1.9.

Comment: According to the error messages, he's using gems installed for Ruby 1.9.1. If he's using those with Ruby 1.8.7 that sounds like a bad idea and may very well be the cause of this problem.